# AsyncController method declarations, assist with understanding syntax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I am looking to implement async coding for some web services.

I came across [a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx) and tried to follow it and implement it however one specific section I am having trouble with.

My example

```
   public void CalculatePricingAsync(QuoteInput obj)
    {

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        var apiService = new ApiService();
        ApiService.CalculatedPricingCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["Pricing"] = e.Value;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
        ApiService.CalculatedPricing(obj);

    }

    public JsonResult CalculatePricingCompleted(string[] pricing)
    {
        var jr = new JsonResult { Data = new { pricing } };
        return jr;
    }
```

The following line taken from the first method above does not exist in the ApiService class.  Can someone explain what this expression is doing and what it means.  Do I just create a method of this name in that ApiService class and leave it blank, does it somehow work with the second method.  I am little unclear what its doing and where the method should be declared and what exactly should be in it.

```
ApiService.CalculatedPricingCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["Pricing"] = e.Value;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
```

this > (CalculatedPricingCompleted) in the line above is showing red in visual studio, it is clearly looking to be defined somewhere.

Comment: Do you have to use .Net 4.0+MVC4? 4.5+MVC5 would result in much easier to read code with `async`/`await`... (not necessarily easier to deeply understand :) )

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, there is no mention of an `ApiService`. Is this a local modification of what you're working on?

Comment: yes,  I changed the classes and method names to my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CalculatedPricingCompleted` is a delegated method inside the `ApiService`. You need to look into the service class and add it. Having said this, I highly recommend using async / await for asynchronous operations in .NET. If you are on .NET 4.0+ there is no excuse not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

I am not restricted to using this approach.  

I will have a look at the async/await operations.